# convert numpy warnings to errors

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:59: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
    warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
```

when I run a code I wrote. This is a large codebase. The problem is, I do not see where in **my code** this warning was fired.

I would rather have this as an error (e.g. an exception), so that I can see where this was generated in my code.

Is it possible to have exceptions instead of warnings?

Note: I solved my problem debugging line by line. But the question still stands.

Answer (score 16):

Setting

```
numpy.seterr(all='raise')
```

should do the trick. You should probably check out the [details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) though.

Comment: It did not. I found the offending line by debugging step by step.

Comment: No, this is the standard library's `warnings` mechanism, not the `seterr()` mechanism.

Comment: my bad, should I delete the answer?

Comment: Worked for me with divide-by-zero warnings though.

Answer (score 5):

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error', "Mean of empty slice.")

# ... Your code here.
```

See the documentation of the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) for more details.